# Accessing Azure Cloud Storage - CloudConfigurationSettings

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-storage

I am accessing Azure storage connection string using the following:

```
Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BlobConnStr"))
```

The above gives me a compile error:

```
'CloudConfigurationManager' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level
```

I have imported these libraries:

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob
```

The connection string is in my App.config file under appSettings:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="BlobConnStr" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=acct_name;AccountKey=acct_key"/>
```

I researched connecting to Azure storage and it looks like I am doing it right. Can someone help me figure out why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager** NuGet package to your project.

```
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Then, import the **Microsoft.Azure** namespace.

```
Imports Microsoft.Azure
```